# Network disappearing for HTTP only

Tags: networking, windows-10, browser, http, timeout

How is it possible, that network disappears for browsers only?

I cannot open router page `192.168.10.1` (addressing by IP) page from this computer from any browser, including `wget`.

Simultaneously I can open other services, like `ssh` and also can open router page from other computers in the same `LAN`.

So, how is it possible on Windows machine, that only outgoing HTTP is disabled?

I don't want to reboot I want to fix it as is.

Error is timeout.

Comment: Are you connecting to the router via SSH or are you accessing some other system by SSH? Can you ping the router's IP address form the affected Windows system, i.e. `ping 192.168.10.1`? If you can't ping its address, can you ping that IP address from other systems?  What are the IP address and subnet mask on the affected Windows system?

Comment: I can ping anything pingable, I can `SSH` to router and other computers, also I can see network shares from affected computer and run remote desktop from affected computer. Mask is `255.255.255.0`

Comment: Can you establish HTTP connections to sites on the Internet? Though I suspect it isn't a proxy server issue if wget is also not working, is the affected Windows 10 system set to use a proxy for HTTP connections? You can [check the system-wide proxy setting from a command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/settings/#commandprompt) by typing `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable` The value will be `0x1` if a proxy server is enabled. If one is enabled, try disabling the proxy server and then try to access the router's webpage.

Comment: Proxy is disabled...

Comment: Are you only experiencing the problem when accessing the router page by HTTP or do you experience the problem when accessing any website by HTTP? E.g,, can you access `http://www.example.com`?  You could try [HTTPSniffer](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/web/HTTPNetworkSniffer/), which can be found at www.nirsoft.net, to see if your Windows 10 system is even sending out a [GET request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) to the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for ["get" requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) being sent to a web server from a browser on your system by [using HTTPNetworkSniffer](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/web/HTTPNetworkSniffer/), which is free and can be downloaded from [HTTPNetworkSniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/http_network_sniffer.html). There's no installation procedure for the program, you just unzip the downloaded zip file and run the executable `HTTPNetworkSniffer.exe` within it. Alternatively, though it may require more understanding of how network protocols work, you could install Wireshark, which is a free network traffic analyzer, to provide even more insight into what is happening at the [Internet Protocol (IP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) and [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) level. By default, Wireshark will show all network traffic, but you can narrow down the display of network traffic by [capturing data and filtering the display of the captured data by IP address or port number](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/tools/sniffing/wireshark/capfilter/), e.g., port 80 for HTTP connections or even [filter by HTTP method](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/tools/sniffing/wireshark/filter_http-get.php), such as for GET requests, which are issued by browsers to webservers to request specific webpages. E.g., you could use a filter of `http.request.method==GET`. Those two tools will give you insight at the underlying network protocol levels, though for HTTPNetworkSniffer it only displays information for HTTP traffic, as to what packets are passing back and forth between the Windows 10 system and the router.